# How do I make my script interpret a user-provided string expression?

Tags: python

I'm trying to develop a python script where I can pass an xmldict argument from the command line and have it return the value.

I know I still need to add the argv code, but right now all I'm trying to do it get Python to read the print statement from a variable. No luck so far. The print statement just prints vv as a string. I'm using 2.7.2 but can use Python 3 if it's easier.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import xmltodict

document_file = open("file.xml", "r") 
original_doc = document_file.read() 
document = xmltodict.parse(original_doc) 

day = document['weather']['dayf']['day']

vv='day[2][\'hi\']'

print "{0} ".format(vv)

print "{0} ".format(day[2]['hi'])
```

Comment: you are surprised that print just prints?

Comment: no, but why is vv not an argument for .format?

Comment: It *is* an argument for `.format`. That much is clear because you provided it as an argument, and the code compiled and executed. Did you expect the *string* value to be *evaluated*? Python doesn't magically evaluate strings. If you give it a string, and tell it to place that string in a formatted expression, it will place that *string* in the formatted expression.

Comment: vv var is a string, so when you do use format on it it replace {0} by the content of the var.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Yes, I want the string to be evaluated. I'm new to python and do not know how.

Comment: So vv = day[2]['hi'] without the single quotes, and print vv prints the value. That was a noob question! But don't I have to place the xmltodict in single quotes on the command line when I pass in the argv so it does not get hung up on the special characters?